# Thousand separator not working right way

Tags: c#, string, winforms, datagridview, separator

I want to display 200000 as 200.000, by set DefaultCellStyle

```
dgrTonKho.Columns["xtkTTN"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "0,.###";
```

but when dispay it just like 200, all zero after the separator has been removed, I don't know why

Comment: try to use `dgrTonKho.Columns["xtkTTN"].DefaultCellStyle.FormatedValue = "0,.###";`

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
dgrTonKho.Columns["xtkTTN"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "#,0.###";
```

From MSDN:

> Thousand separator specifier: If one or more ',' characters is
>   specified between two digit placeholders (0 or #) that format the
>   integral digits of a number, a group separator character is inserted
>   between each number group in the integral part of the output.

Thousand separator must be between two digit placeholders

Comment: It's worked as 98% :) the result look like 600,000. I want to use dot as thousand separator instead of comma, but when I change it like "#.0.###" the result is bad

Comment: Ok, It's depend on my Region setting, thank very much :)

Answer (score 1):

You can dynamically parse the cellvalue

```
 this.dgrTonKho.CellFormatting += new DataGridViewCellFormattingEventHandler(dgrTonKho_CellFormatting);
```

add cellformatting event and try to parse the cell value dynamically it will do the job

```
 void dgrTonKho_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 0 && e.RowIndex != this.dgrTonKho.NewRowIndex)
            {
                double d = double.Parse(e.Value.ToString());
                e.Value = d.ToString("0.00##");
            }
        }
```